# Why velocity animation works only one time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, velocity.js

I'm animating using `velocity.js`, and want to return block when animation completed. So I assign `el[0].style.transform = "translateX(0px)"` and call function again, but animation doesn't work anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/nbLLzqn0/2/

```
var box = $('.box');

function anim() {
    box.velocity({
        translateX: 200
    }, 
    {
        duration: 3000,
        complete: function (el) {
            $('.info').html(el[0].style.transform);
            el[0].style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
            anim();
        }
    });
}

anim();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
el[0].style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
```

To

```
box.velocity({ translateX: 0 },{ duration: 0 });
```

Comment: All ingenious is simple

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to bounce from right to the left, it's called **looping**. Try adding loop:true like this:

```
   duration: 3000,
   loop: true,
   complete: function (el) {
```

Comment: No, I don't need it to bounce from right to left, just repeat the same animation from left to right

Comment: Let's see. The main issue seems to be at the duration. It does not take the duration properly when the complete function is called. It just jumps from 0 px to 200px instantly.

Comment: I noticed that `translate` replacing to `margin-left` fixes issue. http://jsfiddle.net/nbLLzqn0/7/ But that's not good for animating

Answer (score 0):

Use [forcefeeding](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#forcefeeding) -

```
box.velocity({
    translateX: [200, 0]
}
```